# How can I globally prevent lines from overflowing

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, hyphenation, pandoc, overflow

I'm using pandoc with xelatex and a custom template to generate a PDF document from markdown.
Some parts of my document are overflowing on the right side, for example especially long paths that don't contain any spaces or hyphens.

The document should be generated automatically and the content might change drastically, so it's not an option to manually add breaks for those paths via the \hyphenation{} command. I also tried using \sloppy, but that did not work either.

I'm looking for a global option that I can use to prevent text from overflowing and instead force a break in the middle of the word in case there is no better way to contain it in one line.

Comment: are you wrapping your paths in `\url{http../.../../}`  or similar commands to allow them to line break?  `\raggedright` does what you ask but possibly does more than you want.

Comment: @David Carlisle No, some of them are formatted as code blocks using backticks in the markdown source, but some others are included in the text directly without any special formatting. That's why a global option would be preferred.

Comment: if you mark them as code blocks they are going to be `verbatim` by default and verbatim gives you exactly what you ask for,  if that is a line longer than the page width then so be it.  You may (I don't know pandoc detail) be able to configure it to use listings for code blocks (or perhaps it is already)  then you can configure listings to allow linebreaking in some cases. But in any case configuring listings is entirely separate to configuring general paragraph text (and not mentioned in your question) as always a complete small test document would make the question a lot more answerable.

Comment: If you enclose the URL in pointy brackets, it will become a link: `<https://this.is/a/very/long/path/to/some/destination/>` will render as `\url{https://this.is/a/very/long/path/to/some/destination/}`. See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#automatic-links